# Limit as the first coefficient approaches $0$ in the formula.

Tags: calculus, limits, polynomials

I noticed that $\lim_{a\to0}ax^2+bx+c=0$ has $bx+c=0$ or $x=-\frac cb$.

But when looking at the quadratic formula, I noticed $x=\lim_{a\to0}\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ also worked, using L'Hospital's rule.  I also noticed that I get one undefined scenario when I have $\lim_{a\to0}\frac{-b}a$, which is a slight problem.

But besides that, I wanted to know if taking the limit as the first coefficient approaches $0$ for the cubic formula yields the quadratic formula, and if it is safe to say that the solutions to the general $4$th and $5$th degree polynomials (including solutions that are not closed forms) will produce the formula for the polynomial one degree less.

Comment: With $b,c$ fixed, let $x_\pm(a) = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ be the roots of $ax^2+bx+c$. You have correctly observed that $\lim_{a\to0} x_+(a) = -\frac cb$, which is the root of the limiting polynomial $bx+c$; you've also correctly observed that $\lim_{a\to0} x_-(a)$ doesn't exist, which is consistent with $bx+c$ having one root instead of $2$.

Comment: @GregMartin Um... I already knew that...

Comment: You phrased the latter as "a slight problem", so I thought a clarification might help. If it didn't, no big deal. Do you have a cubic formula in mind? Have you taken the limit of it? Is that your primary question, or are you looking for a theoretical argument why the limits might or might not work out from degree $n$ to degree $n-1$?

Comment: @GregMartin I am looking for the theoretical argument, as the actually formulas are a bit gruesome to work with.

Comment: Perhaps you'll want then to prove a statement like the following. Fix $a_{n-1},\dots,a_0$. Let $r_1,\dots,r_{n-1}$ be the roots of $a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$. (For now, assume $a_{n-1}\ne0$ and that the roots are distinct.) Then for all sufficiently small $\epsilon$, the polynomial $\epsilon x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$ has a root close to $r_1$, ..., and a root close to $r_{n-1}$, together with a final root that is huge in absolute value. This is actually not that hard to prove using simple inequalities.

Comment: @GregMartin Could you put that into a more clear answer?  Its still a bit blurry to me.